# How do I filter a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I filter my list so that I create a separate list of just the integers so I can later add them up.

My attempt:

```
dList=  [['A1', 24],    ['A2',  22],    ['A3',  12],    ['A4',  20],    ['A5',  40],    ['A6',  62],    ['A7',  80],    ['A8',  12],    ['B1',  145],   ['B2',  127],   ['B3',  26],    ['B4',  25],    ['B5',  91],    ['B6',  38],    ['B7',  21],    ['B8',  12],    ['C1',  122],   ['C2',  87],    ['C3',  36],    ['C4',  3], ['D1',  0], ['D2',  5], ['D3',  55],    ['D4',  62],    ['D5',  98],    ['D6',  32]]

def totalWales(dList):
    sum = 0
    numList = filter(operator.isNumberType, dList)
    for x in numList:
        sum = sum + int(numList)
    print "Total wales: ", numList
```

Comment: It looks like the integers are simply the second entry in each sublist, so `sum(y for x, y in dList)`.

Comment: `filter` will apply your `operator.isNumberType` predicate to each element of `dList`.  Since each element of `dList` is a `list` and not a number, your predicate will always fail and the filtered list will be empty.

Comment: Also note that `operator.isNumberType()` is deprecated and does not exist in Python 3.  The modern alternative is to use `isinstance(x, numbers.Number)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create a list with the numbers:
numList = [numbers for letters, numbers in dList]

#Set the result of the sum o the numbers to a variable:
result = sum(numList)

#Or if you just need the sum of the numbers:
result = sum([numbers for letters, numbers in dList])
```

Comment: Completely forgot about sum(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list of all the sublist index 1 elements with a list comprehension:

```
dList= [['A1', 24],
        ['A2', 22],
        ['A3', 12],
        ['A4', 20],
        ['A5', 40],
        ['A6', 62],
        ['A7', 80],
        ['A8', 12],
        ['B1', 145],
        ['B2', 127],
        ['B3', 26],
        ['B4', 25],
        ['B5', 91],
        ['B6', 38],
        ['B7', 21],
        ['B8', 12],
        ['C1', 122],
        ['C2', 87],
        ['C3', 36],
        ['C4', 3],
        ['D1', 0],
        ['D2', 5],
        ['D3', 55],
        ['D4', 62],
        ['D5', 98],
        ['D6', 32]]

newlist = [x[1] for x in dList]

print (newlist)
```

prints:

```
[24, 22, 12, 20, 40, 62, 80, 12, 145, 127, 26, 25, 91, 38, 21, 12, 122, 87, 36, 3, 0, 5, 55, 62, 98, 32]
```

To sum without creating a new list:

```
sumDlist = sum(x[1] for x in dList)

print (sumDlist)
```

prints:

```
1257
```

If you need to convert numbers before summing (note this, like my above solution will fail if it's not a number):

```
sumDlist = sum(float(x[1]) for x in dList))
```

Extra:

If you want fast number checking this module is great: http://fastnumbers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html and here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastnumbers

And use like so:

```
from fastnumbers import *

dList= [['A1', 24],
        ['A2', 22],
        ['A3', 12],
        ['A4', 20],
        ['A5', 40],
        ['A6', 62],
        ['A7', 80],
        ['A8', 12],
        ['B1', 145],
        ['B2', 127],
        ['B3', 26],
        ['B4', 25],
        ['B5', 91],
        ['B6', 38],
        ['B7', 21],
        ['B8', 12],
        ['C1', 122],
        ['C2', 87],
        ['C3', 36],
        ['C4', 3],
        ['D1', 0],
        ['D2', 5],
        ['D3', 55],
        ['D4', 62],
        ['D5', 98],
        ['D6', 32]]

sum_of_dList = 0
for sublist in dList:
    if isreal(sublist[1]):
        sum_of_dList += fast_real(sublist[1])
print (sum_of_dList)
```

prints:

```
1257
```

Comment: This will work, this way i can use the new list to get the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by with some `zip` magic:

```
dList= [['A1', 24], ['A2', 22], ['A3', 12], ['A4', 20], ['A5', 40], ['A6', 62], ['A7', 80], ['A8', 12], ['B1', 145], ['B2', 127], ['B3', 26], ['B4', 25], ['B5', 91], ['B6', 38], ['B7', 21], ['B8', 12], ['C1', 122], ['C2', 87], ['C3', 36], ['C4', 3], ['D1', 0], ['D2', 5], ['D3', 55], ['D4', 62], ['D5', 98], ['D6', 32]]
numbers = zip(*dList)[1]
sum(numbers)
```

Here `zip` picks the first and second elements in each list and puts them in separate lists, then index `[1]` will get the numbers.

Comment: I feel like this method would be less efficient, and less clear, than any of the other methods suggested here. Why use `zip` if there is no advantage in doing so?

Comment: @WillDaSilva Clarity depends on who is reading it and what the person is used to, but I do agree that it is less straight forward. In the current use case there might not be that many advantages either, except for being somewhat shorter to write. :-)

Comment: I'm not saying your use of `zip` is unclear, or bad. It's just more than this simple problem requires. At least this might teach some new programmer who comes across this question about `zip`.

Comment: That's why i love Python (and programming in general), there's always more than one way to do something. Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

If `dlist` is always going to be on the format shown, you can get a list of the ints by doing:

```
intlist = [i[1] for i in dlist]
```

This creates a new list from the second element of each sublist.

The same list comprehension syntax can be used to calculate the sum directly of that is all you are after:

```
intsum = sum (i[1] for i in dlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the sum, then simply this will do

```
>>> sum(num for _,num in dList)
1257
```

And by the way,

`operator.isNumberType(obj)`

> Deprecated since version 2.7: Use `isinstance(x, numbers.Number)` instead.

Comment: is unpacking 2 variables in for loop faster than lookup of one?

Comment: Is `x[1]` still considered unpacking?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it

```
dList=  [['A1', 24],    ['A2',  22],    ['A3',  12],    ['A4',  20],    ['A5',  40],    ['A6',  62],    ['A7',  80],    ['A8',  12],    ['B1',  145],   ['B2',  127],   ['B3',  26],    ['B4',  25],    ['B5',  91],    ['B6',  38],    ['B7',  21],    ['B8',  12],    ['C1',  122],   ['C2',  87],    ['C3',  36],    ['C4',  3], ['D1',  0], ['D2',  5], ['D3',  55],    ['D4',  62],    ['D5',  98],    ['D6',  32]]

def totalWales(dList):
    sum = 0
    numList = []
    for x in range(0, len(dList)):
        for y in range(0, len(dList[x])):
            if type(dList[x][y]) == int:
                sum += dList[x][y]
                numList.append(dList[x][y])
    print "Total wales: ", numList

totalWales(dList)
```

I ran through each item in dList, then each item in that array. I checked if that item is an int. If it is an int, then sum and add to numList

Comment: This is needlessly complicated compared to the much simpler approaches using list/generator comprehension.

Comment: @WillDaSilva I answered the question in closest proximity to the original code. What is wrong with that?

Comment: The original code is bad, and we should make no effort to try to make our answers resemble it.

Comment: Code should be easy to read, and the simple way is often better than the complex way. Search about "The Pythonic Way" for more information.